# New to Ubuntu ive installed on dual boot running windows 8.. very buggy and freezes. HELP!

Tags: networking

Hello im new to Ubuntu and im having a little difficulties... i dual boot and im running windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10 and im having issues with storage its lagging it freezes all the time.

I installed Ubuntu thru the easy install for windows can anyone help me, im Eventually goign to leave windows 8 but want to make sure that Ubuntu is the route i want to go with so far i love it but i cant

Answer (score 0):

Wubi and Windows 8 do not behave together.  You cannot use it effectively with Windows 8, as it just generally *does not work*.  That was one of the reasons that Wubi was dropped and removed from 13.04.

What I would suggest is that you use VirtualBox or some other virtual machine software to load Ubuntu onto, so that you can run it while running windows, as Wubi and Windows 8 don't work together.